# Error in starting the minikube via status bar of vscode

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, minikube

I try to start the minikube according to the minikube status bar in vscode.

[image]

But it gives me an error:

> Error while starting Minikube. Error: ! Specified Kubernetes version 1.10.0 is less than the oldest supported version: v1.13.0 ,! You can force an unsupported Kubernetes version via the --force flag ,X Exiting due to K8S_OLD_UNSUPPORTED: Kubernetes 1.10.0 is not supported by this release of minikube

I had installed the minikube via `brew install minikube` command.

When I try to start minikube from command:

```sh
minikube start  
  minikube v1.14.0 on Darwin 10.13.6
❗  Specified Kubernetes version 1.10.0 is less than the oldest supported version: v1.13.0
❗  You can force an unsupported Kubernetes version via the --force flag

❌  Exiting due to K8S_OLD_UNSUPPORTED: Kubernetes 1.10.0 is not supported by this release of minikube
```

Environment information:

- OS: macOS 10.13.6
- minikube version: `minikube version: v1.14.0`
- Docker: Docker 2.4.0.0 is currently the newest version available.
- [Cloud code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-vscode): v1.6.1
- Vscode version: 1.50.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Context: I started minikube two years ago. Recently, I started using minikube again, install the latest version. I can see the old minikube is activated in the Kubernetes context.

Solution: From this [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4756#issuecomment-511965746) and [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8844#issuecomment-664567827), I tried the below command:

```
~ minikube delete --all --purge
  Deleting "minikube" in docker ...
  Removing /Users/ldu020/.minikube/machines/minikube ...
  Removed all traces of the "minikube" cluster.
  Successfully deleted all profiles
  Successfully purged minikube directory located at - [/Users/ldu020/.minikube]
```

Then it works.

```
minikube start 
  minikube v1.14.0 on Darwin 10.13.6
✨  Automatically selected the docker driver
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
  Downloading Kubernetes v1.19.2 preload ...
    > preloaded-images-k8s-v6-v1.19.2-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4: 486.33 MiB
```

Additional context:

I didn't enable the standalone Kubernetes server in the docker desktop.

[image]

Comment: I just wanted to add, in case others tried what I did: minikube can't utilize the Kubernetes instance that comes with Docker Desktop. When you run the 2 commands above, minikube will install a separate version of Kubernetes.